# How do you create vector tiles to represet landmass and oceans

Tags: vector-tiles, tippecanoe

I plan to self-host my own vector tiles and use Mapbox JS to render them in the browser for a design project where I create minimal abstract looking maps of the world. Hosting on Mapbox is not possible due to tile size limitations.

I've been able to get most of the data I need out of OSM (roads etc) just fine and process it using Tippecanoe. But for land and water, I'm having problems. Tippecanoe takes 24 hours to process the raw data and turns several mbs of shapefiles into several gbs.

I'd like to know if there are alternative approaches to the one I'm taking which will require less processing time.

Here is how I'm going about it.

For my use case I simply want to be able to render land as green and water as blue.

I do not need to distinguish between residential or industrial land. Nor do I need to know the difference between a river, lake, sea, or ocean. If it's land I want to color it one shade of green and if its water I want to color it one shade of blue.

I have downloaded Natural Earths 10m land and ocean files but they make Tippecanoe crawl. I think this happens because I need all my tiles to support a max zoom of 12 so I can utilize over zooming. I can't specify a max zoom of 6 for oceans only as if I zoom to 7 the ocean data will not show as the roads in the mbtiles have a max zoom of 12.

It seems rather inefficient to have to process 2gb of data for my use case. I'm wondering if I'm taking the right approach or overlooking a more simple solution?

One thing I considered was not to bother creating ocean data at all in the vector tiles. Instead I'll just color the "background" of the whole world map as blue (assuming this is possible in mapbox js). I'm not sure if this has shortcomings however.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. "Best" questions are somewhat problematic in our Focused question/Best answer model, because there's an inherent subjective component to them.  If you focus on a *faster* solution, you won't have this problem

Comment: Thanks @Vince for the welcome and the heads up. Your right about "best" questions, they are hard to answer. I'll rephrase it.